# scanf get integers and chars in c

Tags: c, scanf

I have to use 'scanf' to get valid int values to an array and other chars to another array ('garbage array) but cannot put this to work and keep receiving warnings like 'warning format specifies type `'char *'` but the argument has type `'int (*)[4]'`.

What I am doing wrong?

```
int array[4];
char numS[4];
char garbage[100];
num = scanf(" %[0-9]d %s", &array, &garbage);
```

I am trying with simple inputs for now '1' or '2'. I want store user input ints in array. I have a for like that:

```
for (i = 0; i<5; i++)
{
  printf("Write your first number");
  num = scanf(" %[0-9]d %s", &array, &garbage);
  printf("\nNew value: %d", array[i]); //Not showing value
}
```

Comment: You have to drop the `&`.

Comment: in array and garbage?

Comment: Do you see any *other* ampersands?

Comment: could be only one but i will try. thanks

Comment: keep receiving same warning and do not work!

Comment: Also, `%[0-9]` is a conversion-specifer, and the `d` after it is not part of it.

Comment: keep receving warning and still not work

Comment: What is your input format?

Comment: Please indicate the assumed input and the allocation to variable.

Comment: Anyway, if you just want to discard `garbage`, you can use assignment-suppression: `scanf("%d%*s", array);`

Comment: I added expected input to question

Comment: `int num; scanf("%d", &num);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%[0-9]d` conversion specifier is for strings of digits followed by letter `d`, e.g. `123d`. It is not for integers.

You should read both sides of your input as strings, and then do integer conversion yourself. Here is an example of a loop that does this:

```
for (;;) {
    char garbage[100];
    int g;
    if ((g = scanf(" %99[^0-9\n\r]", garbage)) != EOF) {
        // Do something with garbage
    } else {
        break;
    }
    char data[100];
    int d;
    if ((d = scanf(" %99[0-9]", data)) != EOF) {
        // Do something with data
    } else {
        break;
    }
    if (g == 0 && d == 0) {
        // Both inputs are empty
        break;
    }
}
```

`%99[^0-9\n\r]` means "up to 99 non-digits except end-of-line characters"; `%99[0-9]` means "up to 99 digits". Space in front of the format specifier instructs the code to skip all whitespace.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/CHnUjz).

Comment: ok but there something wrong with buffer because program do not wait for the user input after the first time

Comment: If i put getchar() works but the input value still not in array

Comment: @pdcc That's because `%[^0-9]` consumes `\n`s and `\r`s as well. For multiline inputs the structure should be different (see the edit).